# How do I focus input element on Asp.Net Core (MVC6) view

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Do You know of a way to add focus to an input element on a razor view for Asp.Net Core. I know this can be done via javascript, but is there a tag for that as well? Either on the input element or the containing form element.

Thanks in advance

Søren Rokkedal

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus>
```

Or

```
@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Or

```
<input asp-for="name"  autofocus/>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. That works as expected in Chrome and IE.